# Как отсортировать переменные по возрастанию при любых значениях

Tags: java

Даны три переменные с возрастом и три переменные max, middle и min соответственно. Необходимо написать код, который выводит в консоль переменные с возрастами при любых заданных значениях.
Как это возможно сделать с использованием if else, без подключения библиотек?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vasyaAge = 20;
    int katyaAge = 26;
    int mishaAge = 17;

    int min = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int max = 0;

    
}
```

}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вот вам код как вы хотите:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vasyaAge = 20;
    int katyaAge = 26;
    int mishaAge = 17;

    int min = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int max = 0;
    if (vasyaAge > katyaAge && katyaAge > mishaAge) {
        max = vasyaAge;
        middle = katyaAge;
        min = mishaAge;
    }
    if (vasyaAge > mishaAge && mishaAge > katyaAge) {
        max = vasyaAge;
        middle = mishaAge;
        min = katyaAge;
    }
    if (mishaAge > katyaAge && katyaAge > vasyaAge) {
        max = mishaAge;
        middle = katyaAge;
        min = vasyaAge;
    }
    if (mishaAge > vasyaAge && vasyaAge > katyaAge) {
        max = mishaAge;
        middle = vasyaAge;
        min = katyaAge;
    }
    if (katyaAge > vasyaAge && vasyaAge > mishaAge) {
        max = katyaAge;
        middle = vasyaAge;
        min = mishaAge;
    }
    if (katyaAge > mishaAge && mishaAge > vasyaAge) {
        max = katyaAge;
        middle = mishaAge;
        min = vasyaAge;
    }
    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(middle);
    System.out.println(max);
}
}
```

Но вообще это спокойно можно сделать в 5 строк кода, но я не знаю Java, поэтому так сходу не подскажу.

Comment: а чего минусуют то ? просили if else,  да громоздко но всё по теме